# Next and previous button for material_tabs in shinymaterial

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

Currently I'm creating a shiny web application with `Shinymaterial` package that comes with tabs on the interface.

But what my issue is if I could make a NEXT and PREVIOUS button on each tab to allow users to move to the next and previous tab. I know this could be done by using `Shinydashboard` but could I do this in `Shinymaterial` package also?

EXAMPLE

```
shinyUI(      
    material_page(    
        material_tabs(
            tabs = c(
                "Home" = "home",
                "Second Page" = "example_2"
                ),
                color = "deep-purple"
        )


        #Home Page
        material_tab_content(
            tab_id = "home"
        )   

        material_tab_content(
            tab_id = "example_2"
        )
    )
)
```

I expect to have 'Next' and 'Previous' button on each tab. For an instance, 'Next' button on HOME tab to move to the SECOND PAGE.